# "Server Error ReferenceError: self is not defined" in use the powerbi-client-react with typescript project

Tags: reactjs, next.js, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, react-tsx

I tried to use the lib powerbi-client-react in my project written in typescript, but I get the following error when I try to run it:

my component code:

```
import { PowerBIEmbed } from 'powerbi-client-react';
import { models } from 'powerbi-client';

// aditional declarete from use "window" in my getEmbeddedComponent
declare global {
    interface Window { report: any; }
}

export default function PbiEmbeddedDashboard() {

    return (
        <div className="App">

            <PowerBIEmbed
                embedConfig={{
                    type: 'report',   // Supported types: report, dashboard, tile, visual and qna
                    id: '<Report Id>', // the information has been filled in correctly in the project
                    embedUrl: '<Embed Url>', // the information has been filled in correctly in the project
                    accessToken: '<Access Token>', // the information has been filled in correctly in the project
                    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed, // i also tried to use the models.TokenType.Aad but the error was the same
                    settings: {
                        panes: {
                            filters: {
                                expanded: false,
                                visible: false
                            }
                        },
                        background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
                    }
                }}

                eventHandlers={
                    new Map([
                        ['loaded', function () { console.log('Report loaded'); }],
                        ['rendered', function () { console.log('Report rendered'); }],
                        ['error', function (event) { console.log(event.detail); }]
                    ])
                }

                cssClassName={"report-style-class"}

                getEmbeddedComponent={(embeddedReport) => {
                    window.report = embeddedReport;
                }}
            />

        </div>
    )
};
```

This is return error:

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: self is not defined

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Object.<anonymous>
file:///home/myProject/sistema-web-myProject/be-front/node_modules/powerbi-client-react/dist/powerbi-client-react.js (1:452)
Module._compile
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (1085:14)
Object.Module._extensions..js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (1114:10)
module.load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (950:32)
Function.Module._load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (790:12)
module.require
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js (974:19)
require
internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js (101:18)
Object.powerbi-client-react
file:///home/myProject/sistema-web-myProject/be-front/.next/server/pages/dashboards/pbi.js (52:18)
__webpack_require__
file:///home/myProject/sistema-web-myProject/be-front/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
eval
webpack-internal:///./src/util/pbiEmbedded/pbi_getAccessToken.tsx (9:78)
```

What sounds strange to me is that I used pretty much the same code in another project written in javascript and everything seems to work fine.

Could you help me solve this problem and understand what is happening?

i also tried to use the models.TokenType.Aad but the error was the same

I didn't find anything related to this

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing an error due to the absence of the window object, which is not available in server-side rendering.

We have the following 2 options to resolve this issue:

Option 1: Check if the window object exists before using it in the code. However, this approach may require to skip code that relies on the window object, which may not be ideal for our use case.

Option 2: Use dynamic imports or lazy loading to only load the code that uses the window object on the client-side. This approach ensures that the code is executed only in the browser, where the window object is available, without requiring to skip any code.

You can try the following code for using dynamic importing:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

import { EmbedProps } from 'powerbi-client-react';

import { models } from "powerbi-client";

const PowerBIEmbed = dynamic<EmbedProps>(() => 
import('powerbi-client-react').then(m => m.PowerBIEmbed), { ssr: false });
```

Please let me know if you need any further assistance or clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Madhav's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76825721/7277094), I believe you might also be using another library along with PowerBIEmbed.

```
import { models } from "powerbi-client";
```

This also needs to be imported dynamically. This is how I achieved it inside useEffect.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const loadModule = async () => {
      const { models } = await import("powerbi-client");
    };
    loadModule();
  }, []);
```

P.S. For me the dynamic import was asking for type of models, so instead I used the useEffect approach. Please let me know if we can import dynamically somehow.